# Why ie7 display not same other browser on this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Why ie7 display not same other browser on this code ?

i test on chrome , firefox and other it's work good.
But why on ie7 display not same other browser, How can i do that ?

```
<script>
window.onload=function(){
var element = document.getElementById('element1');
document.getElementById("element2").style.paddingTop = element.offsetHeight + 'px';
}
</script>

<div id="element1" style="position: fixed; height: 50px; background-color: #000; width: 100%;"></div>
<div id="element2" style="position: relative; width: 100%;">    
    <div id="element3" style="position: relative; height: 50px; background-color: red; width: 100%;">    
</div>
</div>
```

display on ie7 http://image.ohozaa.com/i/5a8/9b1VrQ.jpg

and other browser http://image.ohozaa.com/i/438/zsltSI.jpg

Comment: What exactly about it is not looking the same?

Comment: You're adding padding to the 2nd div. Why would you want it to NOT include the padding? Just remove the padding and it'll look the same

Comment: Chen Asraf , not work

Comment: put something like `* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}` as your first CSS or use any other reset stylesheet to reset browser presets of margin and padding and see if that solves the differences

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised at all if the whitespace between the `div`s makes a difference in IE7

Answer (score 0):

It's not a secret that every browser(almost) has it own engine to render HTML, and IE the most problematic. So I'm also didn't understand question fully but I recommend you to add attribute "height" to the second element manually instead of using paddings(if it will be enough).